# Throwing away inner faces of cubes of a transparent voxel structure in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, rendering, voxels, transparency, shading

I want to create a "*Building site is (not) obstructed.*" indicator for my building system.

How can I throw away those faces which would be hidden if the material would be opaque?

[image]

Comment: A *culling shader* is what you are looking for. I am no shader magician though, so I can't really help :(

Comment: There's a fundamental irony of voxel games that trips up many newcomers: 1) Voxel games look like they're rendering a bunch of individual cube meshes 2) No well-performing voxel game actually does it this way. I recommend taking a tour through previous [tag:voxels]-tagged questions for some existing explanations of techniques for constructing a mesh of only the outermost surface. That said, if you just want a quick & dirty fix for this one case to hide everything but the frontmost surface, [you can use the depth reservation trick shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/166200/39518).

Comment: I just need a trick, because I did some research, then some benchmarking, and I will never use as many voxels that will cause performance issues. 
Even if in some miraculous ways I will have to, then I will combine meshes, optimize in other ways, etc, then. Because I don't want to prematurely optimize. 
Thanks for the link, I will have a look at that.