# Ocean visible through the island's lake in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics, water

I'm working on a puzzle game featuring islands: there is a **plane with a water shader**, and **objects colliding with that plane**.

Now I'd like to make **lakes** on the islands, with **different (higher) water levels** than the ocean's.

[image]

The problem is that if I put a water plane in a "hole", I can see the ocean below at best, or even worse, the upper water surface just glitches out and disappear.

[image]

[image]

One option is that I **move the lake's basin higher** than the ocean's see level. This works, but I it doesn't look so good, because the lake becomes too shallow.

[image]

Another option is that I **cut holes in the ocean's plane**, but that seems a bit overengineered, isn't it?

**Is there a better solution?**

Also having a water plane for every "lake tile" causes some problems:

[image]

but I want to have dynamic lakes, so having a 2x2 water plane for a 2x2 group of lake tiles isn't a walkable path.

Comment: Have you considered rendering a depth-only object below your lake water level to clip out the ocean before it's drawn, [similar to the approach described here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/166200/39518)?

Comment: Not yet, but sounds good. Could you help with the solution in the Answer? I'm a bit newbie with shaders.

Comment: What specific help do you need? How far have you gotten, using the linked Q&A as a guide?

Comment: I just don't get how does it work and thus how could I use that to solve my issue. Under "clip out" you just mean to draw an "opaque, only-depth" face above the ocean? If yes, how would that differ from my current "having a basin object above ocean? if no, how could I have the basin rendered, but the ocean not? I'm a bit confused here :\

Comment: It's similar to the basin solution, but the bottom of the basin is invisible, so you don't have the appearance of a shallow lake with a visible bottom.

Comment: And is there a way to have a basin as well? Having a surface under lakes will may come in handy later on.

Comment: Try it and tell us if you run into any problem.

Comment: Thanks, it was easier than I thought!

Comment: Nice work! Thanks for sharing your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer: [Fade in rendering mode doesn't work as intended](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149675/fade-in-rendering-mode-doesnt-work-as-intended/166200#166200)

I've put a quad just above the ocean's gameobject in my lakes, with a material with this shader:

```
Shader "Custom/DepthReserve"
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "Queue"="AlphaTest+1" }
        LOD 100

        Blend Zero One

        Pass
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So this quad "reserves" the depth, not letting the ocean mesh to be shown.