# Overlap Transparent geometry should Appear with same transparency

Tags: unity, shaders

I am looking for a way to render overlap trasparent geomery with same trasparency. For better understanding here is the way: [image]

Comment: We have some past Q&A about how to do this in the context of [preventing a half-faded model from showing overlaps with itself](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/166200/39518) or implementing a [tag:fog-of-war] effect. There's no clean way in the graphics pipeline to say "just merge this colour with *part* of what was drawn here before", so you either need to block the overlaps from drawing at all, or pre-compose an opacity mask and *then* render it to your scene. Can you help us understand your use case so we can suggest a way that fits your needs?